# Constructors and throwing exceptions

Tags: c#, exception

Is this the best way for me to abort instantiation of an object if it's parameters are not passed in with valid data?

```
protected Command(string commandKey)
{
    if(commandKey == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("commandKey", "Command Key cannot be null as it is required internally by Command");
    if(commandKey == "") throw new ArgumentException("Command Key cannot be an empty string");
    CommandKey = commandKey;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is common practice to validate the arguments in constructors and throw an exception if they are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine. Constructors do not return anything so how else would you know if something went wrong? You could have a bool to set it to some uninitialized state but I would go with exceptions.

Also :

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(commandKey)) //throw exectpion
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the IsNullOrEmpty method!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could use the static method string.IsNullOrEmpty(commandKey):

```
protected Command(string commandKey) 
{ 
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(commandKey))
        throw new ArgumentException("commandKey");
    //something
}
```

Comment: Note that there is also a method string.IsNullOrWhitespace() to check if the string consists only of whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what Microsoft does if you look through the framework source code, so I suspect it is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine if you validate inside a constructor and throw exception if something goes wrong.